# Memory use grows after preallocation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, memory

This is part of a MATLAB script I am working on:

```
gens=zeros(28,28,7,3,5,13);
windows=1:13;
for i=windows
    ...
    for iRes=1:5;
        for type=1:10
            for iter=1:3
                gensNew=RENworkedBronzeGenerate(model,type-1,6,rand(28),iterRes(iRes),0.03);
                for k=1:7
                   gens(:,:,k,iter,iRes,i)=gensNew(:,:,k);
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Where, of course, everything whose declaration is not included is located elsewhere. The preallocation succeeds, however after running for a while, I run out of memory executing line 10. Why would I run out of memory there, even after I preallocate?

Also, the output of `RENworkedBronzeGenerate(...)` is a 28x28x7 matrix.

Comment: What is line 10? Is it the `gens(...)=gensNew(...)` line in the internal-most loop?

Comment: Try to replace line 8:10 to `gens(:,:,:,iter,iRes,i) = gensNew;`, eliminating the `k` loop

Comment: I've tried that `zeros` will not prelocate memory actually while `ones` will. Maybe the implementation of `zeros` uses sort of sparse matrix.